# How to merge three columns into one column along with their data using react-csv?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export-to-csv

I want to export a table whose data is coming from an API. I want to display data of three attributes of the API in a single column (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName as FullName). Also, there is a moment object coming from it, which I want to format into date and time columns separately using the same react-csv Library.

```
const dataToExport = data.map((value:any) => {return {
    ...value,
    LoginTime:moment(value.Login).format("hh:mm A"),
    LoginDate:moment(value.Login).format("DD/MM/YYYY") // There are no dataIndexes LoginTime and LoginDate. Login is the attribute (moment object) coming from the API.
  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow my ideal

```
let newData = oldData.map(item => {
    ...item,
    newProperty: custom value
    })
    // delete some property don't need
    delete newData.oldProperty 

<CSVLink
  data={newData}
  filename={"my-file.csv"}
  className="btn btn-primary"
  target="_blank"
>
```